# jQuery popup function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

After testing the simple jQuery popup trying to implement in my wordpress site http://www.lawandahill.com/ , but popup is not working here. Removed the duplicate jQuery v1.9.1  after getting error `"TypeError: $(…).dialog is not a function Error"`.

Now my site has `jquery-1.7.1.min.js`.

Placed this script in

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
</script>
```

Someone please help . Thank you.

Comment: `dialog()` method is not part of jQuery core, you need to include relevant plugin (jQuery UI???)

Comment: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css and http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js  is included this simple works fine in one of my local site.

Comment: So check your console/network tab, you aren't including it correctly or you are overwritting it by including more than once jQuery

Comment: Found this errors in console might be these are issues   http://dpaste.com/1698718/

Comment: These are warnings, not relevant to your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to download jQueryUI go here http://jqueryui.com/download/ you can select only the modules you need, in this case "Dialog".

Comment: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js, http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css  is included already thankx

Comment: Then be sure you have the Dialog module.

Comment: If the source is 100% identical to the local site maybe it could depend by a missing file, maybe you didn't upload the jquery-ui source? Is there a public url to see it?

Comment: Just look at the browser console ;-) "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui.js:315"

Comment: The problem is that you included jQuery UI before jQuery, it can't work even on your local site, if the code is the same

Comment: You are right i have included them in footer area its working fine. Thank you.

Comment: How do i make the div not hidden by jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a conflict here between `jQuery` and `Wordpress`, try to do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
})
```

or wrap your code inside a closure:

```
(function($){
    $("#dialog").dialog();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Nice syntax, always forget about this one. But if OP is including jQuery more than one, i guess wouldn't fix issue, noConflict() should be used. EDIT: just speculating as we don't know what OP is doing wrong

Comment: Doesnt work :( I  another two jquery jquery.blockUI.min.js?ver=2.60 and jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.45.0-2013.10.17 , are they conflicting ?